# How to split a long table into columns

Tags: longtable

I want to display a long table in latex. But the table has only two columns, thus too narrow, so I decide to split it into four columns.

To be specific, I need to continue the exceeding part on the second column, then the third column, then the fourth, and then on the next page.

Take the following table as an example of two columns:

[image]

Comment: Also, I want the table to be a whole instead of independent columns (like \twocolumns)

Comment: Why can't you just rewrite the table to have more columns? What do you mean by "split into two tables"--is what the longtable package does not good enough? What do you want done differently? Show us [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of your current code so we don't have to guess what packages and settings you're using now.

Comment: My table is to enumerate $x$ and $f(x)$. If I create more columns initially, then it would be hard to control the length of the table and hard to modify. (If I want to add a row, I may have to move the first of the second column to the first column and move the remaining of the second column up together.)